# I am using Chart.js and want to change the tool tip to display date format based on timestamp input

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using Chart.js with Angular2. I am giving input of (x,y) coordinates. where x is timestamp and y are different values. The tooltip displays the timestamp and not the time format i want to see. Here on the pluncker i have done the code please have a look and help me.[PLUNKER for my char.js code using Angular2](http://plnkr.co/edit/MMAPnVhz7S3mhs6w6y5T?p=preview).

I am having little trouble understanding how the x-axis is displaying the time. The Chart.js documentation is horrible and really tough to understand, i am relying on stackoverflow for all my doubts.

Here is the options for my charts that is printing the date. I am unable to understand what to write in tooltip option here.

```
private options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            tooltipFormat:'',
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                displayFormats: {
                    'millisecond': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'second': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'minute': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'hour': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'day': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'week': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'month': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'quarter': 'HH:mm:ss',
                    'year': 'HH:mm:ss',
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the timeformat you want to see ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `tooltipFormat` option is documented here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale

it should be added under the `time` sub option as mentioned in the doc.

> tooltipFormat: The moment js format string to use for the tooltip.

go to https://momentjs.com/docs/ to find the correct format. For example, if you wanted `MM/DD/YYYY` format ie. 04/27/2017 try this:

> plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xntCXNiaL5rFVpy2VATN?p=preview

```
     scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
              tooltipFormat:'MM/DD/YYYY', // <- HERE
              displayFormats: {
                 'millisecond':'HH:mm:ss',
                 'second': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'minute': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'hour': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'day': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'week': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'month': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'quarter': 'HH:mm:ss',
                 'year': 'HH:mm:ss',
              }
            }
        }]
    }
```